# Mongo-ready query from Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How can I serialize an Origin::Selector object into something that I can feed directly into native Mongo?

Currently, to_json gets me nearly there, but I have to wrap certain types such as Date and ObjectId.

As an example, this is what to_json yields:

```
{
    "$and": [
        "archived":false,
        "group_id":{
            "$in":[
                "52289c3cb777888350000002"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but I then have to convert to this before querying mongo:

```
{
    "$and": [
        "archived":false,
        "group_id":{
            "$in":[
                ObjectId("52289c3cb777888350000002")
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there an undocumented way to get the actual protocol query string from a Mongoid::Criteria or Origin::Selector object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible in the current version of Origin. I see that someone else were asking for a similar feature [How can I see raw mongoDB queries with Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960230/how-can-i-see-raw-mongodb-queries-with-mongoid) .

Anyhow, can you file a ticket https://github.com/mongoid/origin/issues/new asking for the feature?

thanks

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for answering. I think I neglected to use the word "raw" when trying to find prior questions!